# Erro ao executar remoção de dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Quando eu clico no botão remover eu removo toda minha linha com esse código, porém ao criar um usuário novo ele não fica sendo ouvido pelo `.click()`

```
inserePlacar = () => {
  let corpoTabela = $(".placar").find("tbody");
  let usuario = $("#input-nome").val();
  let numPalavras = $(".contador-palavras").text();
  let linha = novaLinha(usuario, numPalavras);
  corpoTabela.prepend(linha);
};



$(".botao-remover").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().parent().remove()
});
```

Já tentei colocar isso em uma `function` ficando assim:

```
inserePlacar = () => {
let corpoTabela = $(".placar").find("tbody");
let usuario = $("#input-nome").val();
let numPalavras = $(".contador-palavras").text();
let linha = novaLinha(usuario, numPalavras);
linha.find(".botao-remover").click(removeLinha)
corpoTabela.prepend(linha);
};



removeLinha = (event) =>{
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().parent().remove()
}
```

Mas aí não remove nada.

Comment: Thiago, troque essa parte do código por isto e veja se funciona: `$(document).on("click", ".botao-remover", function (event) {`

Comment: Sam, ou eu não entendi e fiz errado ou não fucionou, ele se comportou igual o primeiro exemplo do meu codigo.

Comment: Cara, deveria funcionar :D... Só as linhas que vc adiciona que não são removidas?

Comment: Exatamente, somente as linhas que são adicionadas pelo JS que não são removidas. as que já estão no html conseguem ser removidas

Comment: Deveria funcionar. Deve ser outra coisa.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta essa função `novaLinha`, acho que vai ajudar a analisar melhor.

Comment: tem como reproduzir o problema no https://jsfiddle.net/ ou aqui mesmo? assim posso testar e achar uma solucao para o seu problema.

Comment: Antes de formular uma resposta eu gostaria de saber de há outros componentes que usam o `id = ".botao-remover"` e caso existam outros objetos com este id se o evento `click` destes objetos é e será sempre o código do `removeLinha `? Pergunto pois pois a solução que imaginei com esses dados pode gerar o efeito colateral de modificar indesejavelmente um evento click.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ThiagoMaha/cknx6mh1/4/  acho que é assim que faz... sou novo nos estudos e não conheço bem as ferramentas

Answer (score 2):

O Bind de eventos e feito no Load da Pagina, quando vc adiciona elementos no DOM após o Load inicia, o Bind dos eventos ja foi feito e não pega os novos elementos adicionados. Porém o jQuery ja preve isso e te permite fazer Binds de eventos e elementos adicionados dinamicamente a pagina ja carregada. Para isso faça de seguinte forma:

o ID bloco_pai é o identificador do elemento no DOM que recebe os elementos dinamicos.

```
$("#bloco_pai").on("click",".botao-remover",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove()
});
```

Desta forma vc esta informando ao jQuery que nesse bloco_pai, haverão elementos adicionados posteriormente, com a classe botao-remover e que deve ser feito o bind do evento click neles.

Comment: Certo mas quem seria o bloco pai? a TR?  <tr>
                            <td>Thiago</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="botao-remover">
                                    <i class="small material-icons">delete</i>
                                </a>

Comment: O bloco pai pode ser qualquer bloco de nivel superior a sua linha de usuários, desde que seja um bloco que é renderizado no Load da pagina, não pode ser algo que é incluido dinamicamente.

```<div id='bloco_pai'>
     sua linha vai aqui
</div>```